# How do I get TFS 2010 Builds to use new build configuration and transform web config

Tags: web-config, web-config-transform

I have a situation where I am using TFS builds to deploy an MVC site to various environments. I would like to use the web.config transforms with the TFS builds to ensure things like connection strings are correct for each environment without me having to edit the web config manually.

I have created new Configurations (using the Configuration Manager in VS2010) for Dev, QA and RC. I also have Web.Dev.config etc with appropriate transformations but am at a loss to get these working with the TFS build definitions I have created.

Any ideas??

**EDIT: Schoolboy error on my part (no offence intended to schoolboys, most would know better!) I didn't check in my solution file and so TFS had no idea I had created new build configurations.**

Answer (score 11):

The TFS Build server will select the correct transformation based on the type of build you are running.  So, you should just need to pick the build type.

To do this:

1. Go edit your build definition
2. On the Process "tab", expand 1.Required and "Items To Build"
3. Click the ellipses on "Configurations to Build"
4. Click Add and type in the particular configuration you want in the Configuration line.  Note that this is a drop down list that does allow you to type into it; the configuration type must match exactly to the named config you have for the transformation.  In your case, if the configuration is named "Dev" then just type in "Dev".
5. Pick the platform.  Usually this is "Any CPU".  However, sometimes you might need to explicitly set it to x86 if you have 32 bit assembly dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the information - I was making a very silly mistake in that I didn't check in my sln file and so TFS had no idea about my new build configurations.